I got the error message PackageNotFoundError("Package not found at '%s'" % pkg_file) using docxtpl
I tried following a YouTube tutorial about using Python and docxtpl to automate MS Word content, but this message popped up 'PackageNotFoundError("Package not found at '%s'" % pkg_file)'. I have checked that the .docx file is in my project file and is not empty as I have a template in the file, I also tried to close the docx file while running the program but it didn't work, it's also not in any virtual environments. What have I done wrong here?
I expect there should be no error.
screenshot_codes

post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly .
Text allows for quick copy and pictures do not.
how to ask
